# Add Angular2 instructions to Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, angular

I used to use Netbeans during my work. Now I want to start using Angular2.

I'm following tutorial from angular.io. I've created template HTML file with content (only relevant line):

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="gotoDetail(hero)">
```

And NB shows me errors about `*ngFor` and `(click)`:

- Attribute "*ngfor" is not realizable as XML 1.0. (Rule Category: Attributes)
- Attribute "(click)" is not realizable as XML 1.0. (Rule Category: Attributes)
- Attribute "*ngfor" not allowed on element "div" at this point. (Rule Category: Elements)
- Attribute "(click)" not allowed on element "div" at this point. (Rule Category: Elements)

How can I teach NB that those are correct? I've already installed plugin to support TypeScript.

In my test project I downloaded node packages:

```
c:\proj> npm list --depth=0
angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 C:\a2
+-- angular2@2.0.0-beta.17
+-- concurrently@2.0.0
+-- es6-shim@0.35.0
+-- lite-server@2.2.0
+-- reflect-metadata@0.1.2
+-- rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
+-- systemjs@0.19.26
+-- typescript@1.8.10
+-- typings@0.8.1
`-- zone.js@0.6.12
```

Comment: What errors? You need Angular2 beta.17.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added what NB shows.

Comment: Ok, that are only warnings from static checks. How does the `doctype` in your `index.html` look like? If you have just `<!DOCTYPE html>` Netbeans shouldn't create these warnings.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added doctype to main `index.html`. But the errors described are in a template file, different than index.html. Besides now I have validation error in `index.html` in line with `<my-app>Loading...</my-app>` which is quite obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately NetBeans does not support Angular 2 template syntax, so you will receive (wrong) warnings/errors and no codecompletion support.
You can use the TypeScript plugin and typings to get support for the TypeScript/JavaScript parts of the application. Feel free to open a NetBeans issue with the request, I will vote for it as well.

Edit:
There is already an issue filed to request that feature: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257587 if you upvote it, it might get implemented.

Comment: Similar bug already issued: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257587 . I've added comment and screenshot.

Comment: Can you suggest any other IDE ?

Comment: Another free IDE that is mentioned in Angular 2 context is Microsoft Visual Studio Code, but I have not tried it yet.

Comment: I'm going crazy to register and vote in netbeans :( the link https://netbeans.org/people/new always redirect to https://netbeans.org/community/index.html any help is welcome

Comment: Problem is known, unfortunately takes some time to get fixed.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, by the way, until Netbeans solves this problems, I'm working Angular with Microsoft Visual Studio Code, and I very happy with it :)

Comment: Glad you found a way. Feel free to check back on NetBeans regularly, I am confident it will improve.

Comment: I REALLY hope Netbeans get this one soon. I love Netbeans and use it for everything up until now. But a new project I'm part of is set to go with Angular 2, and I'd hate to part with it.