# How can I use Angular 4 with NetBeans?

Tags: angular, netbeans

I am using netbeans as editor for my angular 4 application. I created my first application using angular CLI then I opened with netbeans 8.2.  The problem is that I got some error compilation (Example: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)] ="name" >`). That's why I want to know if netbeans support angular 4 ? if yes, where can I find required libraries ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Angular2 instructions to Netbeans IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028505/add-angular2-instructions-to-netbeans-ide)

Answer (score 7):

You have to install Typescript plugin to netbeans. Follow this instructions: [Typescript, Angular 2 and NetBeans IDE](https://jaxenter.com/typescript-angular-2-and-netbeans-ide-an-unbeatable-trio-125443.html)

Note that Angular 2 is fully compatible with Angular 4. So everything work with Angular 2 should work too for Angular 4.